# Finding words from Wordnet separated by a fixed Edit Distance from a given word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am writing a spell checker using nltk and wordnet, I have a few wrongly spelt words say "belive". What I want to do is find all words from wordnet that are separated by a leveshtein's edit distance of 1 or 2 from this given word. 
Does nltk provide any methods to accomplish this? How to do this?

---

May be, I put it wrongly. the `edit_distance` method takes 2 arguments like `edit_distance(word1,word2)` returns the levenshtein's distance between word1 and word2.
What I want is to find edit distance between the word I give with every other word in wordnet.

Comment: Are you sure Wordnet is what you want here?  Seems like overkill.  Enchant may be better:  http://packages.python.org/pyenchant/

Answer (score 1):

It does in fact provide an `edit_distance` method.  See the docs [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.metrics.distance-module.html#edit_distance)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, finally came up with a solution:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
f=open("wordnet_wordlist.txt","w")
for syn in list(wordnet.all_synsets()):
    f.write(syn.name[:-5])
    f.write("\n")

f.close()

f = open("wordnet_wordlist.txt")
f2 = open("wordnet_wordlist_final.txt", "w")
uniquelines = set(f.read().split("\n"))
f2.write("".join([line + "\n" for line in uniquelines]))
f2.close()
```

Now reading from the final wordlist_final file and using nltk.edit_distance the list can be found

```
wordnetobj=open("wordnet_wordlist_final.txt","r")
wordnet=wordnetobj.readlines()
def edit(word,distance):
    validlist=[]
    for valid in wordnet:
        valids=valid[:-1]
        if(abs(len(valids)-len(word))<=2):
            if(nltk.edit_distance(word,valids)==distance):
                validlist.append(valids)

    return validlist
```

Comment: don't know whether it is the efficient way to do it. but it did the job for me